# Nancy.Owin Error Passthrough to Owin AppBuilder pipeline?

Tags: c#, owin, nancy, katana

I have a NancyFx.OWIN application. I'm trying to leverage Katana's diagnostic "ErrorPage" (from http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Diagnostics/2.0.0) to display error Responses returned from my NancyModules.

(Screen shots of katana error page here: http://miso-soup3.hateblo.jp/entry/2013/10/30/205653)

Though I can display errors from the IAppBuilder context to this page, unfortunately I can't get error responses from Nancy displayed to it.

My Owin startup looks like this:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseWelcomePage("/hello");
        NancyOptions nancyOptions = new NancyOptions();
        app.UseNancy(options => 
            options.PassThroughWhenStatusCodesAre(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError))
            .UseErrorPage();  
    }
}
```

this functions as this:
1. "/hello" displays the Microsoft.Owin.Diagnostics blue smiley welcome page
2. The routes defined in my NancyModules function as expected
3. HttpStatusCodes != InternalServerError are handled by Nancy (displaying 'green monster' views)

However when InternalServerError status codes are returned the OWIN IAppBuilder pipeline ignores them. So when I hit the following Nancy route:

```
Get["/error"] = _ =>
    {
        throw new Exception("error!");
    };
```

I would expect the error to be formatted and presented ala the 'UseErrorPage()' functionality owing to my following Nancy exception pipeline which formats all exceptions into responses of InternalServerError :

```
public class ErrorPipeline : IApplicationStartup
{
    public void Initialize(IPipelines pipelines)
    {
        pipelines.OnError += (context, exception) =>
        {

            if (exception is Exception)
                return new Response
                {
                    StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
                    ContentType = "text/html",
                    Contents = (stream) =>
                    {
                        var errorMessage =
                            Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
                                exception.Message);
                        stream.Write(errorMessage, 0,
                                     errorMessage.Length);
                    }
                };

            return HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        };
    }
}
```

However nothing is displayed at all. I know the pipeline error response is being sent back as a response and Nancy is passing it through, but somehow the UseErrorPage() isn't picking it up... When I remove the passthrough, "Error!" is displayed as text in the browser. **Any ideas how to hook NancyFx's error responses into Owin.IAppBuilder pipeline?**

Comment: This blog post is helping me understand the problem... http://byterot.blogspot.com/2013/08/OWIN-Katana-challenges-blues-library-developer-aspnetwebapi-nancyfx.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass-through the errors within the Nancy itself. Just add this code somewhere and it will work.

```
public class ErrorStatusCodeHandler : IStatusCodeHandler
{
    public bool HandlesStatusCode(HttpStatusCode statusCode, NancyContext context)
    {
        return statusCode == HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
    }

    public void Handle(HttpStatusCode statusCode, NancyContext context)
    {
        object errorObject;
        if (context.Items.TryGetValue(NancyEngine.ERROR_EXCEPTION, out errorObject))
        {
            var exception = errorObject as Exception;

            if (exception != null)
            {
                throw exception;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try hooking up the UseErrorPage() middleware before the UseNancy() and try the same scenario? For example:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseWelcomePage("/hello");
        app.UseErrorPage();
        NancyOptions nancyOptions = new NancyOptions();
        app.UseNancy(options => 
            options.PassThroughWhenStatusCodesAre(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the Nancy documentation when a request is passed through the Nancy response is abandoned (even if nancy "returns" it from a route). Because of this there isn't an error within the OWIN pipeline (ie in the form of a NancyResponse) for the katana error display page to display. It would be great if I could configure Nancy to "bubble up" or throw an exception that another OWIN middleware could then handle.